Access blocked: This app's request is invalid
I am develop a google authentication for my web app. I am using the nextjs and also using the next auth for my authentication process.
This is my code for the auth process :
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

const handler = NextAuth({
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
          clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID ?? "",
          clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET ?? ""
        })
      ]
})

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }

